# T4MVC 2.6.65 and UseLowercaseRoutes=true error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Good day!

I'm using latest T4MVC from 2.6.65 from NuGet (upgraded from 2.6.64), I've set

```
// If true, use lower case tokens in routes for the area, controller and action names
static bool UseLowercaseRoutes = true;
```

And I got error:

```
The expression being assigned to '....' must be constant    ...\T4MVC.cs
```

Here is the the generated code that triggers error:

```
    [GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public class ActionNameConstants {
        public const string Calc = ("Calc").ToLowerInvariant();
    }
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah sorry, the previous change broke it. I just pushed a new build of T4MVC (2.6.66) which addresses this. Well, it's more of a workaround as it basically doesn't generate the constant tokens when UseLowercaseRoutes is used. But that'll get us going for now.

The root of the problem is that C# doesn't support using .ToLowerInvariant() in constant strings. Ideally, it would just evaluate that at compile time, but it's not that smart :)